# Exception Handling in java to show user the catch error message from the nested method calls

Tags: exception, try-catch, throws

I have doubt in Exception handling in java,when the exception is thrown in the called method, how to show the catch error in the calling method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to catch exception inside called method, and then re-throw same exception back to caller method.

```
public String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (path));
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("REading file..." + line);
            lines.append(line);
        }
        return lines.toString();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in called method.." + ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Note: It is not possible if you are using try with resources, and exception occurred inside resources itself like opening of file, or file not found. In that case exception will be directly thrown back to caller.